# Devices connected to mac

Tags: macos

How can I list all the connected devices on a mac? All wifi devices, bluetooth devices, usb devices connected till that point of time to the mac need to be listed. Please provide any pointers to API which I can pull the list.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOKit.framework. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html